# Storing a triangle texture in vram with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, language-agnostic, graphics, 3d

Is there any way I can store and draw a triangle texture without having to create a rectangle buffer (and using twice as much storage as I need).

*(I know I could pack lots of triangles into a large rectangle texture, but I would like to see if there is a way todo this without having to waste any space or write a complicated packing algorithm)*

Comment: What is a "rectangle buffer?"

Comment: @NicolBolas a regular texture (rectangular or square).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can try to use this rather simple algorithm to unwrap your textures UVs like this:

```
|\
|1\
|__\
|   \
| 2  \
-------

 _____
|   \1|
| 2  \|
-------
```

Creating a rectangular POT texture with cutting the top of a triangle (1) and placing it in the free space near its base (2).

Comment: Well, the created discontinuity will certainly cause trouble later at texturing. One could of course implement a fragment shader, based on direct texel access and doing the interpolation and filtering manually *shudders*.

Comment: Yep. Some sort of automation is required in such solution. e.g. the maps/polygons could be generated in advance. There seems to be no other solution, cos no hardware supports triangle textures ;)

Answer (score 1):

The usual tack for situations like this is to pack multiple odd shapes onto a single rectangular texture (they need to be separated from each other so that sampling does not bleed colors from neighboring shapes...).  If you use multiple textures for your triangle, you can probably also pack them this way.

If you only have the one texture, it's probably simplest to waste the space -- chances are, your application is not especially resource-intensive?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, neither OpenGL nor any extensions support what you are looking for.